# Download multiple files sharpSSH

Tags: c#, wpf, linux, sharpssh

I have 6 files I want to copy from Windows to Linux: input.dat, image1.tif, image2.tif, image3.tif, image4.tif, image5.tif

I'm using SharpSSH, now I know how to copy a single file, but my question is there anyway I can copy multiple files using sharpSSH instead of doing them one by one?

Here is my code for copying one file:

```
Sftp sshFTP;
string localPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\input.dat";
string remotePath = "/home/mowglin/working_directory";
this.sshFTP.Put(localPath, remotePath);
```

Now this works fine, it copies the input.dat file to Linux, but again how can I send or put multiple files?

Comment: How about zipping the files and extracting them after the upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can use directoryinfo and foreach loop.

```
 DirectoryInfo d  = new DirectoeyInfo( directory where you get your files)
 FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*");

foreach(FileInfo file in Files)
{
    //put your code here
    //your remote path should be "/home/mowglin/working_directoey/" + file.name;
}
```